# Could not write value to key \SOFTWARE is displayed for SSMS Install in a Windows 7 machine with an Administrator account

Tags: sql-server, registry, ssms

I have the following error when installing SQL Server 2014:

Could not write value  to key \SOFTWARE.   Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.
It happens when it tries to install the SSMS and my machine has Windows 7 running. I have done the following things in order to make it work:

•   Run the set up as an admin

•   Reinstall the machine

I found this on a  [Microsoft link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913559) and doesn’t work either

•  Click Start, click Run, type control userpasswords, and then click OK.

•  Create a new computer administrator account.

•  Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.

•  In Registry Editor, right-click HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software, and then click Permissions.

•  Click Add, type Everyone, and then click OK.

•  Under Group or user names, click Everyone.

•  Under Permissions, click to select Full Control in the Allow column, and then click OK.

•  Locate the following subkeys:

1. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software
2. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Setup

•  For each subkey, follow these steps:

1. Click the subkey.
2. Delete the InstanceComponentSet.# string value in the right panel. Notice that # is a number, and the value of this key is {66563AD8-637B-407F-BCA7-0233A16891AB}.

•  Unregister and then reregister the Microsoft Windows Installer service. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Click Start, click Run, type msiexec /unregister, and then click OK.
2. Click Start, click Run, type msiexec /regserver, and then click OK.

Thanks

Allan

Answer (score 4):

I have installed an addware program "adwcleaner" and run it. It has cleaned and remove the malware viruses from my system and then i try to reinstall SQL Server Management tool and it's installed without any error. Thank God.

Here is the website for the "adwcleaner" software.

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old thread but I guess I know the answer so posting if this can be helpful to someone.

Yes this is not related to account issue but this issue is not related to SQL Server as well believe me. What is happening is some registry scanner software, some addware, some Malware is stopping SQL Server installation from writing information to Reg Key /Software that is why this message is coming.

You need to uninstall any such third party software you have installed on your system. Go to add remove program in windows machine and uninstall all such dubious softwares.

I have seen lots of such issue on MSDN forum and an OP finally told the solution and that solution has been helping lot of people so I though of posting here. See answer provided by Michpol In [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/41dec503-ce0a-40e1-ae5f-363452890d48/sql-server-management-tools-could-not-write-value-to-key-software-error-code-1406?forum=sqltools)

As per him

> The solution is as simple as possible.
>
> Win32/Toolbar.SearchSuite.C marked as " potentially undesirable adware" was the reason.
>
> Simple online scanner and no problem.

There is some kind of virus/adware/addone that blocked access to the registry.
The solution was simple: remove that virus from your system with the  scanner on line.

Hope this helps

Comment: This could also be caused by _anti_-malware software trying to protect the registry, so temporality disabling antivirus or similar software could also work.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the installation from an administrator command prompt (and not from Explorer):

```
* Right-click `Command Prompt` and select `Run as administrator`
* cd %HOMEPATH%\Downloads
* INSTALLER.exe (or .msi or whatever)
```

This may not work for all installations, but worked for me with `Meld v3.20.3` (Meld-3.20.3-mingw.msi) on Windows 10, where running the .msi as "Administrator" did not allow the registry key to be created.