# sql server 2014 management studio not supporting windows 8?

Tags: sql-server, windows-8

im tring to insatll sql server 2014 management studio in  windows 8 . but it shows error message that system does not support . How will i install it in my windows 8 or should i go for any other version of sql??

Answer (score 0):

You must tell what edition of SSMS you are trying to install. As per Microsoft [Hardware and Software requirement for SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx) Enterprise and BI edition is not supported on Client OS(Windows 8) but it wont block the installation it will allow you to install. Have yu read the requiremnts ?

Can you please add error message and edition information in your question I would be able to help you better. I strongly suggest you to read [How to use SQL Server on Windows 8](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2681562)

Edit:

> Could not write value to /Softwre

Please add complete details about problem in Question. How do you suggest we can help you with little piece of information. Have a look at This [Stackexchange thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897248/could-not-write-value-to-key-software-is-displayed-for-ssms-install-in-a-window) and also at [this support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913559)

**What you can do**

1.Click Start, click Run, type control userpasswords, and then click OK.

2.Create a new computer administrator account.

3.Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.

4.In Registry Editor, right-click HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software, and then click Permissions.

5.Click Add, type Everyone, and then click OK.

6.Under Group or user names, click Everyone.

7.Under Permissions, click to select Full Control in the Allow column, and then click OK.

8.Locate the following subkeys:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Setup

9.Unregister and then reregister the Microsoft Windows Installer service. To do this, follow these steps:a.Click Start, click Run, type msiexec /unregister, and then click OK.
 b.Click Start, click Run, type msiexec /regserver, and then click OK.

This can also be caused if any malware or addon is running on your system which can block access to the registry. Please clean your system and make sure any unwanted software is removed. `If possible` format the OS and try installing again

Comment: Could not write value to key \SOFTWARE . This is the message .